# Perssion denied while installing hadoop

Tags: hadoop

zsh: permission denied: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/hadoop/3.3.6/libexec/etc/hadoop

termianal is showing this command whil installing hadoop on my m1 mac.
how can i solve this issue.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXsBq.png)

I tried to solve it. And not able to solve it

Comment: 1) Report the issue to the Homebrew github repo, or download Hadoop from official site and extract elsewhere 2) The first output says 3.3.6 is already installed, so apparently there was no permission issue before?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `sudo brew...` to try again.
2. If fails, check the permission of /opt by run `ls -la /opt` and paste it here or you can simply run `sudo chmod 777 -R /opt` not safe , though